# Custom Processing Engine Service Not Working

Tags: configuration, processing, cortex

I'm trying to implement a test Processing Engine service to get started with Sitecore Cortex and ML.NET -> https://www.brimit.com/blog/dive-sitecore-cortex-machine-learning-introduction.

Issue:
I've followed the steps from Part I from the link but it doesn't seem to fire off my custom ML Service. (debug - attaching project to Sitecore.ProcessingEngine service)

What I've Done:
 1.  Added custom project .dll to relevant locations  (I believe)
   - `xconnect\bin`
   - `C:\xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine`
   - `C:\xconnect\App_Data\jobs\
continuous\ProcessingEngine\bin`
2. Added custom service to `C:\xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\ProcessingEngine\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\Processing\sc.Processing.Engine.ML.Services`

```
<IMLNetService>
   <Type>Feature.Cortex.Controllers.MLNetService, Feature.Cortex</Type>
   <As>Feature.Cortex.Controllers.IMLNetService, Feature.Cortex</As>
   <LifeTime>Transient</LifeTime>
   <Options>
      <TestValue>0.25</TestValue>
   </Options>
</IMLNetService>
```

3. I tried to attach my project to Sitecore.ProcessingEngine service but it doesn't hit any break points.

Am I missing something in my configuration? Or am I inputting the MLNetService node into the wrong xml config file?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @LinkedListT! To hit breakpoint your should run a task that stats processing. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/register-a-task.html or https://www.brimit.com/blog/cortex-ml-4-processing-engine-workers-dictionary-agents-task-manager

Comment: @x3mxray so inorder to access the breakpoint without creating the test API, I need to create the Task Manager (Projection => Merge => Train => Evaluate)? P.S. awesome tutorial!

Comment: exactly. If you just want to test breakpoint, you can register task only for one Projection worker (it is a place where you inject MLNetService) and run it by processing engine agent (in config) or from your sitecore instance (by code). You can download source code here https://github.com/x3mxray/Cortex.Demo.RFM if you need